# Pytorch autograd doesn't give correct second order gradient

Tags: pytorch, autograd

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
import numpy as np

class MTLModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_sizes, num_tasks):
        super(MTLModel, self).__init__()
        self.shared_layers = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(input_size, hidden_sizes[0]),
            nn.ReLU()
        )
        for i in range(len(hidden_sizes) - 1):
            self.shared_layers.add_module(f'hidden_layer_{i+1}', nn.Linear(hidden_sizes[i], hidden_sizes[i+1]))
            self.shared_layers.add_module(f'relu_{i+1}', nn.ReLU())

        self.task_specific_layers = nn.ModuleList()
        for i in range(num_tasks):
            self.task_specific_layers.append(nn.Linear(hidden_sizes[-1], 1))

    def forward(self, x):
        shared_output = self.shared_layers(x)
        task_outputs = []
        for task_layer in self.task_specific_layers:
            task_output = task_layer(shared_output)
            task_outputs.append(task_output)
        return task_outputs

# Define the training function
def train(model, train_data, train_targets, num_epochs, batch_size, learning_rate, alpha, gamma):
    criterion = nn.MSELoss()
    optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)

    num_batches = len(train_data) // batch_size

    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        epoch_loss = 0.0
        epoch_monotonicity_penalty = 0.0*np.ones(train_targets.shape[1])
        epoch_slope_penalty = 0.0
        epoch_output2_constraint_penalty = 0.0
        epoch_output3_constraint_penalty = 0.0
        epoch_slope_penalty = 0.0
        for batch in range(num_batches):
            batch_data = train_data[batch*batch_size:(batch+1)*batch_size]
            batch_targets = train_targets[batch*batch_size:(batch+1)*batch_size]
            batch_data = torch.tensor(batch_data, dtype=torch.float32, requires_grad=True)  # set requires_grad to True
            batch_targets = torch.tensor(batch_targets, dtype=torch.float32)
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            task_outputs = model(batch_data)
            task_gradients = []
            task_gradient2s = []
            task_losses = []
            for i, task_output in enumerate(task_outputs):
                task_loss = criterion(task_output.squeeze(), batch_targets[:,i])
                task_losses.append(task_loss)
                
                # Apply the monotonicity constraint
                task_gradient, = torch.autograd.grad(task_output.sum(), batch_data, create_graph=True, retain_graph=True)
                monotonicity_penalty = -task_gradient.mean().clamp(min=0.0)
                task_loss += alpha[i] * monotonicity_penalty
                epoch_monotonicity_penalty[i] += monotonicity_penalty.item()
                
                task_gradient2, = torch.autograd.grad(task_gradient.sum(), batch_data, create_graph=True, retain_graph=True)
                
                print('1st gradient\n',task_gradient)
                print('2nd gradient\n',task_gradient2)
                
            loss = sum(task_losses)
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
            epoch_loss += loss.item()
            
        print('Epoch %d Loss: %.4f Slope Penalty: %.4f ' % (epoch+1, epoch_loss/num_batches, epoch_slope_penalty))
        print('epoch_monotonicity_penalty',epoch_monotonicity_penalty)
#%%
# Generate random data
num_samples = 100
num_features = 1
np.random.seed(100)
data = np.linspace(0, 1, num=num_samples).reshape(num_samples,1)
targets = np.zeros((num_samples, 3))
targets[:,0] = -0.5+0.5*np.cos(data[:,0]) + 0.2*data[:,0]**2+0.1*np.random.normal(size=(num_samples))
targets[:,1] = data[:,0]**3 + 0.1*np.random.normal(size=(num_samples))
targets[:,2] = 2*data[:,0]**4 + 0.1*np.random.normal(size=(num_samples))


# Define the model
input_size = num_features
hidden_size = [64,128,64]
num_tasks = 3
model = MTLModel(input_size, hidden_size, num_tasks)

# Define the training parameters
num_epochs = 200
batch_size = 32
learning_rate = 0.001
alpha = [0,0,0] #[0,0,0]

gamma = 0

# Train the model
train(model, data, targets, num_epochs, batch_size, learning_rate, alpha, gamma)
```

I am writing a MTL program for regression. I want to impose constraints on the 1st and 2nd order derivatives in the loss function, so that the curve always increase with the output and the increase becomes faster with the increase of input.

The program always give zeros for task_gradient2 though task_gradient is not constant.

So, I appreciate if someone could check my code to see where it is wrong.